# Display only first module of a position

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-module

Is there a way to limit `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="xhtml" />` to display only the first published module of this position?

It should respect the ordering present in **Module Manager**, the purpose of this is to show a certain module only if the date is valid and if it unpublishes because of the date, the next valid module is shown without needing assistance from a user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very easy way to do that. Install Advanced Module Manager and you can easily configure the module position to display the correct module.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there'd be free option, but I'll take a look at this.